# Is there a solution for x for $x^2+(y-\sqrt[3]{x^2})^2=1$?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I tried to solve this equation (heart shaped function) for x, but cannot get a nice solution. Why?

$x^2+(y-\sqrt[3]{x^2})^2=1$

The formula is taken from this image:

[image]

I just wanted to rewrite the formula in order to be able to solve by $x$.

Comment: it is $$x^2+((y-x^2)^{1/3 })^2=1$$?

Comment: It doesn't have a ``nice'' solution.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Could you explain more about your identification of curves, please? I am "convinced" the curves are different (quotes are because I doubt a bit since it is you who says it and I respect what you say in MSE)

Comment: If you really want to solve for $x$ I can get some very long roots

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by solve? You can put it in the form
$$ y = x^\frac{2}{3} \pm \sqrt{1 - x^2} $$
or
$$ y = |u|^3 \pm \sqrt{1 - |u|} $$
where $u = x^\frac{3}{2}$, but I don't think there is a nice solution in the form x = f(y), since this involves finding the inverse of a third degree polynomial.

Comment: yes, i wanted a nice solution in the form of x = f(y). can you explain what exactly *finding the inverse of a third degree polynomial* is? what is the third degree polynomial and why is finding its inverse so hard? thanks!

Comment: A third degree polynomial is something of the form f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d (where a =/= 0). There is not really a simple answer why something does not have a nice solution. Finding an inverse for, for example f(x) = x^3 + x is equivalent to solving f(x) = y <=> x^3 + x = y. You can try, but there is no nice solution. See also http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2Bx%3Dc and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2+\left(y-\sqrt[3]{x^2}\right)^2=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left(y-\sqrt[3]{x^2}\right)^2=1-x^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y-\sqrt[3]{x^2}=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y=\sqrt[3]{x^2}\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

If you want to solve $x$ (get $x$ as function of $y$) it becomes very messy!

Comment: thanks! can you explain why it gets messy when solving by x?

Answer (score 0):

To get an idea of what you're asking for, here is the *first* solution:

$$x=-\sqrt{-y^2+\frac{14 \sqrt[3]{2} y^3}{\sqrt[3]{-216 y^5-783 y^4-450
   y^3+144 y^2+\sqrt{4 \left(-42 y^3-42 y^2+6 y+5\right)^3+\left(-216 y^5-783
   y^4-450 y^3+144 y^2+126 y-11\right)^2}+126 y-11}}+\frac{14 \sqrt[3]{2}
   y^2}{\sqrt[3]{-216 y^5-783 y^4-450 y^3+144 y^2+\sqrt{4 \left(-42 y^3-42 y^2+6
   y+5\right)^3+\left(-216 y^5-783 y^4-450 y^3+144 y^2+126 y-11\right)^2}+126
   y-11}}-\frac{2 \sqrt[3]{2} y}{\sqrt[3]{-216 y^5-783 y^4-450 y^3+144
   y^2+\sqrt{4 \left(-42 y^3-42 y^2+6 y+5\right)^3+\left(-216 y^5-783 y^4-450
   y^3+144 y^2+126 y-11\right)^2}+126 y-11}}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{-216 y^5-783 y^4-450
   y^3+144 y^2+\sqrt{4 \left(-42 y^3-42 y^2+6 y+5\right)^3+\left(-216 y^5-783
   y^4-450 y^3+144 y^2+126 y-11\right)^2}+126 y-11}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{5
   \sqrt[3]{2}}{3 \sqrt[3]{-216 y^5-783 y^4-450 y^3+144 y^2+\sqrt{4 \left(-42
   y^3-42 y^2+6 y+5\right)^3+\left(-216 y^5-783 y^4-450 y^3+144 y^2+126
   y-11\right)^2}+126 y-11}}-2 y+\frac{2}{3}}$$